# Why I have a standard field Case.isStopped field on one environment but I don't have the same field on the second environment?

Tags: case, administration, sobject, standard-objects, release

I have a field Case.isStopped (label: Stopped) on my Developer organization which I created 2 weeks ago but I don't have that field on full copy Sandbox that was created a long time ago

Can it be because of the different versions of Salesforce?

Comment: Do you have When you use Entitlement & Milestones in full copy sandbox?

Comment: I don't use Entitlement process at my full copy Sandbox - so I think this can be the reason of the difference

Answer (score 1):

If you have Entitlement and Milestones then you will be able to use IsStopped attribute on Case object but it is not any standard field we have in Case Object.

As you confirmed in comment that you done have Entitlement process in sandbox because of which you are not able to use that attribute